# could not find function "geom_text"

Tags: r

I am looking for the reason why I am getting the "could not find function "geom_text"" error.
Enter the following commands to generate a PCA graph with captions on the graph of each "dot":

```
counts <- read.delim('case_vs_control.txt', sep="\t", header=T, row.names=1)
counts <- as.matrix(counts)
design <- data.frame( condition=factor( c("case", "case", "case", "case", "case", "case", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control") ) )
rownames(design) <- colnames(counts)
dataset <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = counts, colData = design, design = ~condition)
dds <- DESeq(dataset)
rld <- rlog(dds, blind=FALSE)
names <- c("0099-M9-PGA-rep1", "0099-M9-PGA-rep2", "0099-M9-PGA-rep3", "0223-M9-PGA-rep1", "0223-M9-PGA-rep2", "0223-M9-PGA-rep3", "0099-M9-rep1", "0099-M9-rep2", "0099-M9-rep3", "0223-M9-rep1", "0223-M9-rep2", "0223-M9-rep3")
pdf("PCAall.pdf")
plotPCA(rld, intgroup=c("condition")) + geom_text(aes(label=names),vjust=2, size = 2)
dev.off()
```

Unfortunately, I am only able to generate a chart without sample captions on the chart (assignment of a specific dot to a specific sample).

I will be grateful for help :)

Comment: Can you include any relevant `library()` calls?

Comment: Do you have `ggplot2` loaded?

Comment: Put `library(ggplot2)` before your codes. Do `install.packages("ggplot2")` if it returns package not found

Comment: At first i included library(gplots2). Now as suggested by the leaf I have installed ggplot2 (because if I understand correctly it is a different library than gplots2). However, when I try to enable this library, I get the following error: Error in value[[3L]](cond) :
   Package 'ggplot2' version 3.4.0 cannot be released:
  Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace 'ggplot2' is imported by 'DESeq2', 'phyloseq' cannot be removed
In addition: Warning message:
package 'ggplot2' was built in R 4.1.3

Comment: What version of R are you using?

Comment: It worked! I have captions for every point on the PCA chart. I have a last question, how can I increase the font of the captions of each point. What argument should I add to this command to increase the font size?                                                         
 png(filename ="PCA label.png", width = 1000, height = 1000)                                 
Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Your question has been closed, so if you have a new question, please ask a separate question with a reproducible example.